# How to add bootstrap to NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, mdbreact

I've had a problem with mdbreact package, because when i am adding some components like buttons, etc. I am getting error: "Window is not defined". I made a research and found that window object is defined only on the client side.
Is it possible way to add Bootstrap to NextJS???

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Updated answer (2020)

react-bootstrap supports SSR as of v1.0

Source: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3569

---

### Outdated answer (2018)

At the time of writing, there is only one "clean" way: using [Dynamic Components](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#3-with-no-ssr) to disable SSR for those component.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const ButtonWithNoSSR = dynamic(import('react-bootstrap/lib/Button'), {
  ssr: false
})
```

The "dirty" way would be to make react-bootstrap support SSR by mocking the window object.

Comment: It's okay but it's generate a lot of code if i have for example 7 or more imports from library

Comment: You could use regular bootstrap CSS classes with your code, or better then, have StyledJSX setup for CSS in JS

Comment: How about other ui frameworks like material design bootstrap for react???

Comment: Ok, i forgot about this approach (adding css class)

Comment: A stated loud and clear that this answer was "at the time of writing" the only way. Updated the anwser. Next negative review I will be forced to delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use bootstrap cdn, your can simply use _app.js or _document.js files in nextjs.

Here is how i linked bootstrap cdn to my nextjs project via _document.js

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <link
                        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
                        crossorigin="anonymous"
                    />
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

To know more about _document.js [click here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

You can also use _app.js in a similar way. for more information about _app.js [check this out.](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)